# Get item in list of strings containing the time of your computer

Tags: vb.net, console-application

Don't really know if this is the best way to set the title to but I'll give more info here.

Hi,

What I'm doing is this:

```
For Each item In bossesList
    Dim time as DateTime = DateTime.Now
    If item.Contains(time.ToString("HH:mm")) Then
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString.Split(" ")(1))
    End If
Next
```

This checks my list if an item contains lets say 00:00 and displays this item.

This is the format of an item in the list:

```
(00:00 UTC+1)   Shadow Behemoth: [&BPcAAAA=]
```

I'm splitting the string so it will output "Shadow Behemoth: [&BPcAAAA=]", the time changes every 15 minutes so its 00:15, 00:30 etc. What I want to do is still display this item until the time is 00:15 and then switching to the next one which is "(00:15 UTC+1)   Shadow Behemoth: [&BPcAAAA=]" etc etc.

This is in a console application btw if you didn't notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the current time, get the latest 15 minute.

```
Dim timeToken As String
Dim time as DateTime = DateTime.Now

timeToken = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", time.Hour, (time.Minute - (time.Minute Mod 15)))

For Each item In bossesList
    If item.Contains(timeToken) Then
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString.Split(" ")(1))
    End If
Next
```

I would also suggest you use a dictionary instead of a list. That way you won't need a loop. And store your information in a class instead of a string, then you could use (for example) item.Description instead of trying to split a string.

Comment: Should "That way you won't need a list" be "That way you won't need a **loop**"?

Comment: Yeah its probably better to use a dictionary, will change this later.

Code works like a charm, thanks alot man